How to assign individual IP to Multiple WordPress websites install to Bitnami NGINX SSL Stack
I wanted to add multiple WordPress instance to same VM.
The default one is installed in
1 . /opt/bitnami/wordpress
2. I installed a second one at /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress2

Also I have added multiple IPs to same VM.
How do I put the settings for each WordPress to be linked to particular IP address ?

Why? This costs you more, uses up a finite resource and creates technical complications for managing routing.


how do i put the settings for each wordpress to be linked
to particular IP address ?

While this is not how web servers generally work (you can happily run thousands of WordPress on one IP adress), you can achieve this by binding your WordPress (your webserver) instances to vHosts using different listeners.
Your domain names will still have to point to the different ServerName's. Hint: You can just use one IP and point all the domains to that one - the ServerName directive will happily redirect requests to your directory of choice, regardless of which IP it used. Think twice if you really really have to use a multihomed (web-)server in this use case.
Apache does this through the Listen directive:
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
Listen 192.0.10.1:80

By default it is already set up for listening on all IPs (the were present at startup):
Listen *:80

Your folders will then be seperated by the vhost config. This example can (almost identical) be found in the vhost documentation:
# Ensure that Apache listens on all the port 80's
Listen 80

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/wordpress"
    ServerName www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.6.100:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress2"
    ServerName www.example2.com
</VirtualHost>

tldr; use vhosts with ServverNames to route requests to sites [folders] instead of IP bindings. You will need hostnames for TLS anyway.

Found the answer to the concern

Add 2 public ips to the vm
Add 2nd wordpress installations
add new configuration files which set the dns setting to recognize the 2nd wordpress installations
There is no need to assign ip routing to individual Ips.
When the domains are pointing to different ips of the VM, the domain have separate public ips.
Internally when the dns resolution will happen, the 2nd wordpress will be automatically called when internal dns points to sub directory.
So the 2nd domain will have now unique ip as well the first domain ( separate primary ip)


Just use name-based virtual hosts. You don't need a separate public IPs for two different wordpress instances, that's a waste. Give us a favor, do more sustainable management.

"[...] when internal dns points to sub directory" this is not how DNS works at all.
